# UIStackView different show hide animation between ios versions

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

`UIStackView` hide show animation is very different between ios versions. Here is a basic setup. I have a `UIStackView` with three arranged subviews inside it. And `UIScrollView` contains `UIStcakView`. I use auto layout. The stack view code is this:

```
let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [view1, view2, view3])
stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

stack.axis = .vertical
stack.distribution = .fill
stack.alignment = .fill
```

The code that makes animation is this:

```
isHidden.toggle()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
    self.view3.isHidden = self.isHidden
}
```

When this runs on ios 10 simulator the animation is correct.

[image: ios 10 animation]

However in ios 13 the animation is not correct.

[image: ios 13]

So is there a way to make this animation just like on ios10? Or should I use `UITableView` instead of `UIStackView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to decrease priority for view3 height constraint.

UIStackView hides it's subviews by constraining their height to 0, so if you have other constraints for view height, they will conflict with the stack view.

Comment: Indeed this is the case. By default every nslayoutconstraint has required priority when created. This is same both for ios 10 and 13. But It seems the way UIStackView handles constraint priority has changed in ios 12. Setting prioriy to defaultLow for height constraint solved the problem. Thanks.